# Using BFS to find all paths between two nodes

Tags: algorithm, path, breadth-first-search

Is it possible to find all the possible paths from s to t (s, t are vertices) in polynomial time? if it is what's a possible algorithm for it?

Comment: The number of paths from s to t can be exponential in the size of the graph, so depends on what you mean by "finding". Counting them? Possibly. Listing them? No.

Comment: @DanielA.White Reread the FAQ.

Comment: How do you define "path"? If duplicated edges are allowed, there could be infinitive many paths.

Comment: Not duplicates, no loops, but just to store them in an array. Now that I think of it, I think it's O(n!) time :/ . But just to make sure, can it be done in O(n^m) for some constant time m?

Comment: @user2580016 If you want to store all of them explicitly, then it can't be done in polynomial time.

Comment: Nitpicky detail: Polynomial *in what*? Number of nodes/edges? Polynomial in the number of pahts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to, in polynomial time, enumerate all those nodes and edges in your graph that *can* be part of a path from s to t. For example, in the graph

```
s --> a --> t
       \
        \--> b
```

those nodes are {a}, because there is no path from s to t that goes through b.

It is also possible to enumerate those nodes and edges that *must* be on *any*
path from s to t in polynomial time.

You can also *count* the number of paths from s to t as long as you do not allow loops in polynomial time; for example, when the graph is acyclic or when put in a restriction that you only count paths that do not contain loops, in polynomial time.

But you cannot *enumerate* all non-looping paths from s to t explicitly in polynomial time just because there can be exponentially many of them. Even in acyclic graphs, e.g.

```
   o   o   o         o
  / \ / \ / \       / \
 s   o   o   o ... o   t
  \ / \ / \ /       \ /
   o   o   o         o
```

assuming the graph is directional from left to right; this has 2<sup>n</sup> paths from s to t if there are n diamonds within it.

Finding the *longest* path from s to t is NP-hard, i.e. no polynomial algorithm.

Calculating the maximum number of *non-intersecting paths* from s to t is also NP-hard, that is, if you want to enumerate a set of paths from s to t so that there is no common edge between any two paths in your set.

Comment: LongestPath is linear for DAGs and [polynomial for trees](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11263/longest-path-in-an-undirected-tree-with-only-one-traversal).